# What is the cause of my sqlalchemy.InterfaceError and how do i access an image stored as a hex(using PIL pillow) by using url_for()?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm creating a basic social network with python-flask and sqlalchemy. This includes a profile photo, header photo and post photos. Ive been following Corey Schafer's python flask sqlalchemy tutorial to implement the header and profile photo features using PIL Pillow. This was rather simple and works as expected. The problem is trying to replicate this in the Post model, as opposed to the User model.

Below is my successful implementation of the profile_img and header_img features.

**routes.py**

```
def save_profile_img(form_profile_img):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_profile_img.filename)
    profile_img_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    profile_img_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/profile_pics", profile_img_fn)

    output_size = (225, 225)
    i = Image.open(form_profile_img)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(profile_img_path)

    return profile_img_fn

def save_header_img(form_header_img):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_header_img.filename)
    header_img_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    header_img_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/profile_pics", header_img_fn)
    form_header_img.save(header_img_path)

    output_size = (700, 700)
    i = Image.open(form_header_img)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(header_img_path)

    return header_img_fn

@app.route('/profile/<id>-<firstname>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def profile(id, firstname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    firstname = User.query.filter_by(firstname=firstname).first_or_404()
    # edit profile form
    form = EditProfile()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.profile_img.data:
            profile_img_file = save_profile_img(form.profile_img.data)
            current_user.profile_img = profile_img_file
        if form.header_img.data:
            header_img_file = save_header_img(form.header_img.data)
            current_user.header_img = header_img_file
        current_user.firstname = form.firstname.data
        current_user.lastname = form.lastname.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        current_user.city = form.city.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', id=current_user.id, firstname=current_user.firstname))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.firstname.data = current_user.firstname
        form.lastname.data = current_user.lastname
        form.email.data = current_user.email
        form.city.data = current_user.city
    profile_img = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + user.profile_img)
    header_img = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + user.header_img)
    return render_template('profile.html', title='Profile', profile=profile, posts=posts, user=user, firstname=firstname, profile_img=profile_img, header_img=header_img, form=form)
```

**model.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    profile_img = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default="default.png")
    header_img = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default="default_bg5.jpg")
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    work_history = db.relationship('Employment', backref='author', lazy=True)
    education = db.relationship('Education', backref='author', lazy=True)
    about = db.relationship('About', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.id}', '{self.firstname}', '{self.lastname}', '{self.email}', '{self.city}', '{self.profile_img}', '{self.header_img}')"
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfile(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name',  validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    profile_img = FileField(validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    header_img = FileField(validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    city = SelectField('City', choices = [('Brampton', 'Brampton'), ('Etobicoke', 'Etobicoke'), ('Brampton', 'Brampton'), ('Markham', 'Markham'), ('Mississauga', 'Mississauga'), ('North York', 'North York'), ('Oakville', 'Oakville'), ('Ottawa', 'Ottawa'), ('Pickering', 'Pickering'), ('Scarborough', 'Scarborough'), ('Toronto', 'Toronto'), ('Vaughn', 'Vaughn')])
    submit = SubmitField('Update Account')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != current_user.email:    
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError('Email is already in use.')
```

With this feature, a User can click upload file button, pick a JPG or PNG file, see the file is displayed before submission, and click submit. Each image is then stored as a hex within the given static files.   I can access the `user.profile_img` and `user.header_img` wit the below `url_for()` statements, which are at the bottom of the route, just before the `render template` statement.

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
profile_img = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + user.profile_img)
header_img = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + user.header_img)
```

I can then add these to the HTML with a simple jinja2 statement `src="{{ profile_img }}"` and `src="{{ header_img }}"`

**THE PROBLEM**
As for implementing a `post_img` feature, I'm running into a slew of issues. At this point, i dont know how to access the images via a url_for statement and I'm getting an sqlalchemyInterface error upon submission. However, the file does indeed get renamed as a hex, and stored in the appropriate static file.  My question is twofold? Why am i getting a sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError?  and how do i access the image via a url_for with it's post_ID so that if a user does indeed upload an image to their post, it will appear, 
Below is the form.py, routes.py, model.py and _postform.html.

**routes.py**

```
def save_post_img(form_post_img):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_post_img.filename)
    post_img_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    post_img_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/post_pics", post_img_fn)
    form_post_img.save(post_img_path)

    output_size = (700, 700)
    i = Image.open(form_post_img)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(post_img_path)

    return post_img_fn

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if current_user.is_authenticated == False:
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    user = current_user
    profile_img = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + user.profile_img)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(content=form.content.data, post_img=form.post_img.data, author=current_user)
        if form.post_img.data:
            post_img_file = save_post_img(form.post_img.data)
            post_img = post_img_file
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post Successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', id=current_user.id, firstname=current_user.firstname))
    post_img = url_for('static', filename='post_pics/post_img.jpg')
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts, profile_img=profile_img, form=form, user=user, post_img=post_img)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)  
    post_img = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True) 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.content}', '{self.post_img}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    post_img= FileField(validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

**_postform.html**

```
<div class="content-section bg-light">
    <form novalidate action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                    {% if form.content.errors %}
                    {{ form.content(placeholder="What's on your mind?", class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.content.errors %}
                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %} 
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    {{ form.content(placeholder="What's on your mind?", class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                    {% endif %}    
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="file-upload" class="post-file-upload">
                    <i class='far fa-image fa-2x'></i>
                </label>
                    {{ form.post_img(placeholder='JPG or PNG', id="file-upload", type="file") }}
                {% if form.post_img.errors %}
                {% for error in form.post_img.errors %}
                    <span class='text-danger'>{{ error }}</span><br>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn custom-btn") }}
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**The traceback error**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO post (content, date_posted, post_img, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('here is a pic, i hope..', '2020-01-07 21:02:46.223754', <FileStorage: '0008beb24a17e995.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 2)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1245, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/bluecaller/routes.py", line 41, in home
db.session.commit()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1027, in commit
self.transaction.commit()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 494, in commit
self._prepare_impl()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 473, in _prepare_impl
self.session.flush()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2470, in flush
self._flush(objects)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2608, in _flush
transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2568, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
rec.execute(self)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute
persistence.save_obj(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 239, in save_obj
_emit_insert_statements(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1136, in _emit_insert_statements
result = cached_connections[connection].execute(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1095, in _execute_clauseelement
ret = self._execute_context(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1245, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/Users/joshmolot/bluecaller/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO post (content, date_posted, post_img, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('here is a pic, i hope..', '2020-01-07 21:02:46.223754', <FileStorage: '0008beb24a17e995.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 2)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

*NOTE that in routes.py, `post_img = url_for('static', filename='post_pics/post_img.jpg')` is set to a test image called post_img.jpg. This picture appears when using the jinja2 statement `{{ post_img }}`. This is because I don't know how to access the post_img so this a hard coded test img.  Ive tried a number of different statements, all of which give me some kind of error.

as for the sqlalchemy error, IMO it has to be coming from the route some where.  My Post model and User model use the same statements for profile/header_img as post_img.  The implementation of pillow is working.  If i change the route as shown below,  the image is still stored to the static file and no error occurs.
Before change

```
form = PostForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(content=form.content.data, post_img=form.post_img.data, author=current_user)
        if form.post_img.data:
            post_img_file = save_post_img(form.post_img.data)
            post_img = post_img_file
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post Successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', id=current_user.id, firstname=current_user.firstname))
```

After change

```
form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(content=form.content.data, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post Successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', id=current_user.id, firstname=current_user.firstname))
```

Any help and insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!  Thanks for tip in terms of the file storage object. First I got the image to actually save to the Post model. I did that by saying 
`post.post_img = post_img_file` 
I confirmed it was stored to the db with 
`>>> p = Posts.query.all()`
once i achieved that I was getting an error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"
So i deleted the the url_for in the routes and simply made the following jinja2 statement in my html `{{ post.post_img }}` and this returned the hexadecimal file. So i wrote the url_for statement accounting for None type stored within the db.
I wrote this in my forms:

```
form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(content=form.content.data, post_img=form.post_img.data, author=current_user)
        if form.post_img.data:
            post_img_file = save_post_img(form.post_img.data)
            post.post_img = post_img_file
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Post Successful!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    # list of posts by descending time
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).all()
    for post in posts:
        if post.post_img != None:
            post_img = url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_img)
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts, post_img=post_img, profile_img=profile_img, form=form, user=user)
```

this worked with no errors, in the route, but jinja2 was still throwing me the cannot concatenate NoneType error, so i had to account for it within the html as well, and did that with the following:

```
 {% if post.post_img != None %}
      <img class='img-fluid mx-auto post-img' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_img) }}"> 
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance (because there's a lot here)...

`[parameters: ('here is a pic, i hope..', '2020-01-07 21:02:46.223754', <FileStorage: '0008beb24a17e995.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 2)]`

Note you're actually setting `post_img` as a `FileStorage` object, not what I suspect you need to be a string, or in the earlier examples, the return value of `save_post_img()`.

I suspect in the latter `routes.py` you need to change:

```
post = Post(content=form.content.data, post_img=form.post_img.data, author=current_user)
if form.post_img.data:
    post_img_file = save_post_img(form.post_img.data)
    post_img = post_img_file
db.session.add(post)
```

To something more like:

```
if form.post_img.data:
    post_img_file = save_post_img(form.post_img.data)
    post_img = post_img_file
post = Post(content=form.content.data, post_img=post_img_file, author=current_user)
db.session.add(post)
```

So that you create the `post` after you've got the return from `save_post_img()`.

That's a guess.  Hopefully this puts you in the right direction at least.

Comment: tried it but still got the interfaceError.  I wonder why it works for the user model and not the post model?

Comment: I think i found where the problem lies.  in the post_img form route, i have post_img = post_img_file.  for the header and profile_img, i have current_user.profile_img = profile_img_file.   i need to find a way to say "current_post", instead of current_user, which I'm unsure how to do